# How to open dialogs depending on what tabs are active in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this setup, http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/LQg7W/34/.

How can the dialogs opened depending on what tabs are active?

Something is missing there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var theSelectedTab = 0;
$( "#tabMe" ).tabs({ select: function(event, ui) { 
theSelectedTab = parseFloat(ui.index);

    }
});
    $('#edit1').click(function() {
        $('#edit_'+(theSelectedTab+1)).dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Tested: it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should only need to do this?

```
if (theSelectedTab == 0) {
    $("#edit_1").dialog("open");
} else if (theSelectedTab == 1) {
    $("#edit_2").dialog("open");
}
```

In the `if(){}` block you were assigning a `live()` handler but not actually triggering anything.

**Adjusted [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/LQg7W/37/).**

Comment: If "theSelectedTab" return's a number, you can actually write it this way: $('#edit_'+theSelectedTab+1).dialog('open');